# What are pure actions in React Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, redux, react-redux

I'm learning [redux saga](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga) but don't get what the author means by the below:

> Contrary to redux thunk, you don't end up in callback hell, you can
> test your asynchronous flows easily and your actions stay pure.

Any examples of "callback hell" and "pure actions" would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Pure Functions

Pure functions are a type of function that, when given the same arguments, will **always** produce the same result, and doesn't modify any variables that are outside of its scope.  For example,

```
function addTwoIntegers(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

If we pass a=2 and b=3, then the result will always be 5.  Nothing else is changed.  This is a good thing, because it makes testing that function much easier - we know with certainty what they output will be for a given pair of inputs.

Contrast this with, for example, a function that loads data from an API and assigns it to a variable:

```
let result;

function AddIntegerToNumberFromServer(a) {
    fetch('api/numberGenerator').then(function(res) {
       result = a + res.data.number;
    });
}
```

In this case, we can call the function with the same argument multiple times, and not be certain of getting the same result.  The consequence of this is that the function is much harder to test - we probably have to create a mock of the api.  We also have to be certain what the initial value of result was in order to know if our function worked as planned.

### Callback Hell

As you probably know, callbacks are functions that we pass as arguments to another function, so that we can defer execution of some code until the second function has completed.  Callback hell occurs when we get many layers deep into this - as commented by someone above jQuery seems to invite this style - for example:

```
$(function() {
    $('#element').click(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(function() {
            $('#anotherElement').fadeIn();
        }
    }
}
```

The issue here is primarily one of human understanding of the code, and ease of readability.  Imagine if this went more layers deep (not uncommon) how difficult it could be to work out what is happening and when.

Redux-thunk is far from the worst offender when it comes to callbacks, and the readability factor can be mitigated by using promises instead of callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

> ... your actions stay pure ...

My best guess is that this is a mistake.  In [the redux-thunk README](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) there is no action creator that is impure let alone an action object that is somehow impure.  Perhaps "impure actions" is referring to a pattern by which "higher level" action-**creators** like `makeSandwichesForEverybody` contain multiple side effects and are therefore very hard to test.

> ... end up in callback hell ...

Again `makeSandwichesForEverybody` contains many nested promises which might become harder to fathom as the async work flow becomes more complex.  What I can't yet comment on is how much simpler / complex this would be implemented in redux-saga.

```
function makeSandwichesForEverybody() {
  return function (dispatch, getState) {
    if (!getState().sandwiches.isShopOpen) {

      // You don’t have to return Promises, but it’s a handy convention
      // so the caller can always call .then() on async dispatch result.

      return Promise.resolve();
    }

    // We can dispatch both plain object actions and other thunks,
    // which lets us compose the asynchronous actions in a single flow.

    return dispatch(
      makeASandwichWithSecretSauce('My Grandma')
    ).then(() =>
      Promise.all([
        dispatch(makeASandwichWithSecretSauce('Me')),
        dispatch(makeASandwichWithSecretSauce('My wife'))
      ])
    ).then(() =>
      dispatch(makeASandwichWithSecretSauce('Our kids'))
    ).then(() =>
      dispatch(getState().myMoney > 42 ?
        withdrawMoney(42) :
        apologize('Me', 'The Sandwich Shop')
      )
    );
  };
}
```

As an aside I have used ["impure action creators", which I call `dispatchers`](https://github.com/AJamesPhillips/napthr/blob/1120b40d67d4ce023b9f863b1103847044ad4dd3/app/src/app/shared/state/user_registration/dispatchers.ts) in the form of functions that acts as action creators, dispatcher and has side effects.  I have found this to be a good pattern for managing async work.  However it makes isomorphic apps harder / impossible to implement and is not easy to test.